# What is the best approach for serializing BigDecimal/BigInteger to ProtocolBuffers

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am starting to migrate a custom serialization mechanism to Protocol Buffers. One data type that will be used particularly regularly is `BigDecimal`.

Does anyone know of a good way of serializing this within Protocol Buffers? Our current serialization routine uses `BigDecimal.toPlainString()` for serialization, and `new BigDecimal(String)` for deserialization - I'm assuming there's a better way.

My guess is to define a `BigDecimal` as:

```
message BDecimal {
    required int32 scale = 1;
    required BInteger int_val = 2;
}
```

But I am not too sure how to define `BigInteger` - perhaps using its `toByteArray()` method?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes.  You should define BigInteger as BigInteger.toByteArray() .

My guess is that BigDecimal would be:

```
message BDecimal {
  required int32 scale = 1;
  required BInteger int_val = 2;
}
```

while BigInteger may be defined as

```
message BInteger {
  required bytes value = 1;
}
```

The code to handle BigInteger would be:

```
  BInteger write(BigInteger val) {
    BInteger.Builder builder = BInteger.newBuilder();
    ByteString bytes = ByteString.copyFrom(val.toByteArray());
    builder.setValue(bytes);
    return builder.build();
  }

  BigInteger read(BInteger message) {
    ByteString bytes = message.getValue();
    return new BigInteger(bytes.toByteArray());
  }
```

Comment: How would you convert a BigDecimal to a BigInteger and scale? And back ?

Comment: I was at first concerned that this approach of using `toByteArray` may not be portable (cannot be meaningfully deserialized from languages other than Java - often one of the main reasons for using protobuf in the first place). However, the specification for [`BigInteger.toByteArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray()) is quite specific and easily usable from other languages (for example [.net BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207(v=vs.110).aspx), although you have to be careful as endianness appears to be different).

Answer (score 12):

I have recently had the same need as OP, and used a similar solution to the one proposed by @notnoop. Posting it here after seeing this comment from @stikkos:

> How would you convert a BigDecimal to a BigInteger and scale? And back ?

According to the `BigDecimal` class [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-java.math.BigInteger-int-java.math.MathContext-):

> The value of the `BigDecimal` is (`unscaledVal` × <sup>10-`scale`</sup>), rounded according to the precision and rounding mode settings.

So, a `java.math.BigDecimal` can be serialized considering three properties:

- [`unscaledValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#unscaledValue--)
- `scale`
- `precision`

---

Now, the code.

1. Protobuf v3 message definition:

   ```
   syntax = "proto3";

   message DecimalValue {
     uint32 scale = 1;
     uint32 precision = 2;
     bytes value = 3;
   }
   ```
2. How to serialize a `java.math.BigDecimal` to a Protobuf message:

   ```java
   import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
   import DecimalValue;

   java.math.BigDecimal bigDecimal = new java.math.BigDecimal("1234.56789");
   DecimalValue serialized = DecimalValue.newBuilder()
           .setScale(bigDecimal.scale())
           .setPrecision(bigDecimal.precision())
           .setValue(ByteString.copyFrom(bigDecimal.unscaledValue().toByteArray()))
           .build();
   ```
3. How to deserialize the Protobuf message back to a `java.math.BigDecimal`:

   ```java
   java.math.MathContext mc = new java.math.MathContext(serialized.getPrecision());
   java.math.BigDecimal deserialized = new java.math.BigDecimal(
           new java.math.BigInteger(serialized.getValue().toByteArray()),
           serialized.getScale(),
           mc);
   ```
4. We can check the obtained `java.math.BigDecimal` yields the same original value as follows:

   ```java
   assert bigDecimal.equals(deserialized);
   ```

---

Note: OP assumed there is a better way to serialize a `java.math.BigDecimal` than using a plain `String`. In terms of storage, this solution is better.

For example, to serialize the first 100 decimals of π:

```
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
```

```java
System.out.println("DecimalValue: " + serialized.getSerializedSize());
System.out.println("String: " + StringValue.of(pi).getSerializedSize());
```

This yields:

```
DecimalValue: 48
String: 104
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to change it? Just because you can or is there a real need (like a profiling session confirming, that serialization/deserialization takes most of the time).

I would use a string, just because it is built in :)

The proposed byte array approach ([What is the best approach for serializing BigDecimal/BigInteger to ProtocolBuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051732/what-is-the-best-approach-for-serializing-bigdecimal-biginteger-to-protocolbuffer/1052049#1052049)) seems fine to me, if string representation seems to be an issue.

Comment: I assume that it's a network optimization problem rather than performance optimization.  String requires a lot of memory.  Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647) for example requires in the order of 24 bytes as a string but only 8 bytes as byte array.